# Stay in Berlin for one night near Tegel airport

Tags: germany, safety, hotels, berlin, solo-travel

I have to stay in Berlin for one night. 
Please recommend me some places which are cheap, closer to public transport, food joints and safe. I do not mind staying in dormitories as long as its safe and provides basic facilities. I am a male, solo traveller.

I would prefer a place in a walking distance from Tegel airport and closer to public transport as I may need to take a bus to Göttingen on the next day.

Comment: Are you a solo traveler? Are you a female? I'm asking out of curiosity for the safety concern. ;)

Comment: Berlin is a big place! Where abouts in the city are you looking to stay?

Comment: You won't beat couchsurfing on price.

Comment: @JoErNanO I am a solo traveller, male but inexperienced. And I would prefer a place in a walking distance from Tegel airport and closer to public transport as i may need to take a bus to gottingen on the next day.

Comment: In Berlin, you don't have to worry about a place being close to public transport or not. It's a very well-connected city. There's always a U-Bahn (Metro) or bus station at a walking distance. Of course, there are exceptions, but I am saying you really don't have to worry about that problem.

Comment: Where do you take the bus to Göttingen? or are you taking a train from Berlin main station, as your other question suggests?

Comment: @Vince I am yet to decide that. My primary choice was train, but recent strikes got me worried.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Meininger Berlin Central Station](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/MEININGER-Berlin-Central-Station/Berlin/35885). It is half-hotel half-hostel, so you can find good rooms and facilities for low prices. I've stayed there twice in their hostel style 4-bed rooms. Nice, clean, and no problems. It is literally next to the fairly new Berlin Central rail station, which connects you to all the major parts of the city (and other parts of the country or other countries) by train, and also has many bus routes that include an express service to both airports. It is also in reasonable walking distance of the major tourist attractions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Sunflower Hostel](http://www.sunflower-hostel.de/) that is near Warschauer Str. It's not exactly central, but near public transport, and last time I took a short walk from Berlin Ost station. If you cross Warschauer Str. from there, you end up in the heart of Friedrichshain, with lots of restaurants and bars.